# Duplicate Unity Ads Library in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, unityads

I am using unity3d in my android studio project and need to import the unity ads aar file into my project. To do so I added the following lines and the unity-ads.aar to the libs folder :

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation files('libs/unity-ads.aar')
```

I get the following error when I compile the project :

```
Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-unity-ads-4.2.1-runtime (com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.2.1) and jetified-unity-ads-runtime (unity-ads.aar)
```

If I delete these lines and the unity-ads.aar file all the classes from unity3d aren't recogonized and I get errors.

I don't understand why the classes are duplicated and how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: How can I avoid this error ?

Answer (score 2):

You only need the first line
`implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])`

and make sure you update your gradle version to 7.x.x

file -> Project Structure

[image]

Comment: I still get the same error after keeping just the first line. My gradle version is 7.3.3

Comment: have you tried to clear gradle cache?